# C++ Linux Input File and Output File Commands

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

I am recently new to using the Linux terminal and for my school project we are expected to write a program and use Linux commands to execute the program which includes an input and output file.  I have never used Linux for input and output files when programming.  I emailed my professor with questions on how to execute the commands and have never received a response.  He mentioned in class that the command should look like:

```
 ./mipssim -i INPUT.bin -o OUTPUT.txt
```

With my main function being:

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 }
```

When trying to get the input file to work I have received the error

```
 ./mipssim line 5: $'\r': command not found
```

and

```
 g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-i'
```

I am extremely confused to what is happening and searching around on the internet has not helped me.  I have gotten the program to execute once and the output to the terminal was completely wrong.

Lastly, I was told that "mipssim" should be the name of my executable, so would this be achieved by renaming the a.out file?

```
 mv a.out mipssim
```

Thank you for your time and feedback!

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose errors without seeing the code that generates them.

In general, the Linux terminal uses its own commands, so ordinarily a "program" using Linux commands would be written as a shell script, not written in a separate programming language like C++. I may, therefore, be misunderstanding your question. But if you need to call a Linux command from within a C++ program, you can always use _[system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)()_.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it is hard to fix the mistakes without seeing the program, but all I need to do is pass the input file and output file name into the program using the terminal.  I've looked up guides on how to do so and none of them have worked.  How would I write a bash script to run this program though?

Comment: In "./mipssim -i INPUT.bin -o OUTPUT.txt " ... assuming mipssim is the c++ executable, then the next 4 space delimited items are delivered in argv's.  If you have no guidance on the "-i" and "-o" options and how to identify them as options, I would simply drop these (unless required).  Using argc and argv, "INPUT.bin" would be argv[2] and "OUTPUT.txt" would be argv[3], and those are all you need to identify the two file names you need for your program.

Comment: @2785528 Thank you! I actually had a problem with one of my bin files so that was giving me all of the trouble!  On another note is changing the c++ executable as easy as renaming the a.out file or is there something else that I would need to do?

Comment: Why not just tell your compiler to name the executable it creates what you want instead of the default a.out?

Comment: @Shawn I have never had to do this before and didn't know that you could tell the compiler what to name the executable.  I'm assuming I would just edit my Makefile to do this?  If so how would I do it, thanks!

Comment: Some of the interesting parts of my g++ command, rename the output using the -o option:,  "g++-7 -std=c++17 -m64 -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic   mipssim.cc  -o mipssim "  ( I typically have another 50 compiler options, with multiple link options following)

Comment: @2785528 Wow! I honestly appreciate the help so much!  For more information on these topics I'm assuming I would just have to look into Bash scripting?

Comment: Oop, previous comment wrong -- Using argc and argv, with 2 inputs, "INPUT.bin" would be argv[1] and "OUTPUT.txt" would be argv[2].

Comment: Yes, the shell you use influences how to present commands and parameters.  On linux, there exists a default shell, and it is easy to try other shells.  I forget how as I seldom need to know.